# What class should be used for param thymesVar

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

In IntelliJ I'm using the `thymesVar` comment to resolve variables used in Thymeleaf expressions.

I'm wondering what should be in there to resolve the `param` variable.

For example, when I have this in the Thymeleaf template:

```
 <div th:if="${param.error}" class="alert alert-danger">
     <p>Invalid username and password.</p>
 </div>
```

Then what should be the type

```
 <!--/*@thymesVar id="loginCommand" type="something.to.resolve.param"*/-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is a little late and you've probably learned it by now.
But for other readers, `param.error` is a String array.
So `type="java.lang.String[]"`.

You can double check this by using `th:text=${param.error.class.name}`.

Comment: Thank you for the generic approach with `.class.name` to figure out the type. Now I don't have to dig in the project anymore. Hopefully IDEA will be able to resolve the variables in the future, the bug report is open for a long time.